# Why MSVC does not prefer non-template overloaded function over template one?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I am not able to figure out why the following code (with undefined `USE_TEMPLATE_SPECIALIZATION`) compiles fine with Clang but fails with Visual Studio 15.5.5:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Defining USE_TEMPLATE_SPECIALIZATION fixes MSVC but breaks CLang...
//#define USE_TEMPLATE_SPECIALIZATION
//-----------------------------------------------------
#ifdef USE_TEMPLATE_SPECIALIZATION
template<typename Enum>
struct EnableBitMaskOperators {
    static const bool enable = false;
};

template<typename E>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<EnableBitMaskOperators<E>::enable, bool>::type
isSet(E e, E mask)
{
    using underlying_t = typename std::underlying_type<E>::type;
    return (static_cast<underlying_t>(e) & static_cast<underlying_t>(mask)) != 0;
}

#define ENABLE_BITMASK_OPERATORS(x)  \
template<>                           \
struct EnableBitMaskOperators<x> {   \
    static const bool enable = true; \
};
#else //-------------------------------------------------
template<typename E>
constexpr bool enable_bitmask_operators(E) { return false; }

template<typename E>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<enable_bitmask_operators(E{}), bool>::type
isSet(E e, E mask)
{
    using underlying_t = typename std::underlying_type<E>::type;
    return (static_cast<underlying_t>(e) & static_cast<underlying_t>(mask)) != 0;
}

#define ENABLE_BITMASK_OPERATORS(x) constexpr bool enable_bitmask_operators(x){ return true; }
#endif
//-----------------------------------------------------
namespace NOne {
namespace NTwo {
enum class ENUM_FLAGS {
    NONE = 0,
    ONE  = 1,
    TWO  = 2,
};
ENABLE_BITMASK_OPERATORS(ENUM_FLAGS);
}}
using namespace NOne::NTwo;

int main(int, char**)
{
    auto a = ENUM_FLAGS::NONE;
    std::cout << (isSet(a, ENUM_FLAGS::TWO)? "Should not happen" : "Bitwise flags work!") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It is clear why defining `USE_TEMPLATE_SPECIALIZATION` in line 5 breaks Clang, but, surprisingly, it fixes MSVC.

I would really like to figure out why the second approach, non-template function overload, doesn't work with MSVC (I really hope it's not an MSVC bug, as I believe it used to work) and will appreciate your help!

Thank you for looking!

Comment: Yes, this seems like MSVC regression: I've just switched the Platform Toolset from "Visual Studio 2017 (v141)" to "Visual Studio 2015 (v140)" and the code with undefined USE_TEMPLATE_SPECIALIZATION compiled fine!

Comment: Shorter version of the code in Godbolt's Compiler Explorer:
https://godbolt.org/g/BM8H1z

Even older compilers like CLang 3.8 or GCC 5.1 compile this code, only MSVC  19 fails...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this does look like a regression. Can you enter an issue on the VC++ Developer Community at https://aka.ms/vs-rap?

Comment: Submitted a bug via VS2017 Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem yesterday, it's been triaged and is now in "Under Consideration" state.

Comment: Probably a bug in two-phase lookup... `enable_bitmask_operators` is a dependent name because its argument type is dependent, and treating it as non-dependent would yield exactly the observed behavior.

Comment: Thank you! If you let me know the title that you submitted it under I might be able to speed up the triaging of it.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/193285/regression-non-teplate-overloaded-function-is-not.html